# Is it worthwhile to go past 40 strength/dexterity?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I've been reading regarding builds in Dark Souls 2 but I haven't been able to find an answer to my question. I do know that before reaching that amount, the increase in attack for either strenght or dexterity for each point ranges from 2 to 4 per point, but past 40 it is reduced to 1 to 2.

Currently I have a melee character with level 250 or so and even though I have added faith to the mix in order to be able to use some pyromancy, I'm not sure as to which direction to go to past this point.

So, in short and as the title says: ***is it worthwhile increasing strenght and/or dexterity past 40?***

***NOTE:*** To clarify further, this question is to decide whether to continue the development of the character towards Strength/Dexterity or to continue towards another discipline such as Miracles. The question itself is just to know the worthiness of continuing that path (using my leveling points in Str/Dex) rather than asking which path to follow.

Comment: You need some calculations, based on each weapon. I haven't seen anything like this with weapons. Reddit has something similiar with the different armor sets - not scaling, but comparision: http://www.reddit.com/r/DarkSouls2/comments/220v9f/dark_souls_2_armor_speadsheet_and_armor_customizer/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When looking at equipment, you will see that they have a modifier, ranging from S being best, A being second, down to E being worst scaling, next to none. This scaling converts a percentage of that specific stat when you use that weapon or armor.

To see how much this bonus is actually affecting you, equip the item, then in the equipment screen, simply hover over it and look at the stats to the right. Say a weapon had 100 physical damage, with an A Strength rating and B Dexterity rating, with you having 40 of each. The weapon's damage will still be 100 physical damage, but beside that number will be a blue +x, the x being the bonus granted by the scaling.

While leveling your stats might appear miniscule when you look only at the stats card, you will notice a vast improvement if you were to wield a weapon with B scaling over a weapon with E scaling. Even if the weapon with E scaling appeared more powerful, in the end, the B scale would have the greatest potential.

In this regard, leveling Strength and Dexterity will provide the character with increased damage, but less versatility. It is not unheard of for a character to focus on multiple skills, such as being competent with melee and magic, or a magic user that has strong defensive capabilities.

A character who has split talents will not be as proficient in all of them, but will be better suited to take on many situations. As an example, the boss

> Ichorous Earth, of Iron Keep, just before the Primal Bonfire, is a large boss that is present only in lava.

A melee character can, feasibly, combat this boss, but a magic or ranged user will have an easier time with it. A character that is proficient in many roles may have an even stronger upperhand. In truth, it is all a matter of preference and playstyle.

Comment: I think the question might have been misunderstood, let me add a note to the question to clarify that.